# Call and send transaction function call without having to build transaction [web3.py]

Tags: web3.py, brownie

Right now, when I want to send a transaction, I have to build it, sign it, and then send it like so:

```
function_call = contract.functions.function_call(parameters)
transaction = function_call.buildTransaction({'chainId': 42,
                                                  'from': my_address,
                                                  'nonce': nonce})
signed_txn = w3.eth.account.sign_transaction(transaction, private_key=os.getenv('PRIVATE_KEY'))
tx_hash = w3.eth.send_raw_transaction(signed_txn.rawTransaction)
```

This seems like a lot more work than what could be done. Is there a way to do something like:

```py
contract.function_call(parameters, {'from': private_key})
```

Like in [brownie's](https://github.com/eth-brownie/brownie) syntax?